# username/password for ftp

Tags: unix, vim, text-editors

I tried to download the rpm for vim from ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/vim/vim-minimal-6.3-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm . I am using "ftp" command in AIX.
when I use,

> open public.dhe.ibm.com

It's prompting for username/password. But no information regarding this is given on the linked page. How do I download the rpm using "ftp" command?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The access is by anonymous but why would you like to do that?

`wget ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/vim/vim-minimal-6.3-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm`

works like a charm. If you want to get knowledge then use man ftp read rfc and wiki page.

Comment: Well there is no wget in AIX!. I tried "man ftp" but can't find anything related to this user/pass issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can compile it from source... Its really useful tool. I cannot live without it. But yeah that wasnt actually a question. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Use "anonymous" as username, any password will work (I just pressed the return key).

Sample session:

```
$ ftp public.dhe.ibm.com
Connected to dispmy-112.mul.ie.ibm.com.
[...]
Name (public.dhe.ibm.com:***): anonymous
331 Guest login ok, send any password.
Password:
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you should be able to use:

```
ftp ftp://user:password@host/path/to/file
```

To get your file with a user/password combo.